# C# - Disposing a specific timer whenever required from multiple running timers

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, system.timers.timer

I have created a code that schedules a job at an interval of time entered by the user which uses a method that run a background thread as a task and the scheduling is taken care by System.Threading.Timer class. The user has the option to schedule multiple jobs at same time according to which specific task will occur but the timer method that drives them is same based on the interval input by user. Now if the user want to cancel a specific job, how do I do that? Please help I am new to this field! 
Below is outline for reference as I cannot post the complete code:

Button Click => application take jobname, jobtime, interval and calls a method

Below is my scheduler code =>

```
public void ScheduleTask(int Year, int Month, int Day, int hour, int min, double intervalInHour, Action task)
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime firstRun = new DateTime(Year, Month, Day, hour, min, 0, 0);
        if (now > firstRun)
        {
            firstRun = firstRun.AddDays(1);
        }
        TimeSpan timeToGo = firstRun - now;
        if (timeToGo <= TimeSpan.Zero)
        {
            timeToGo = TimeSpan.Zero;
        }
        var timer = new Timer(x =>
        {
           task.Invoke();
        }, null, timeToGo, TimeSpan.FromHours(intervalInHour));
        timers.Add(timer);
    }
```

User can schedule multiple number of jobs, but if he wants to cancel one, How should I handle it? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: so if there are 20 jobs you will have 20 timers running ? this isn't the most efficient way of doing this.

Comment: Your question is too broad. It's not clear what `Timer` class you're using, but all of the implementations in .NET provide a mechanism for stopping the timer. Obviously, you would need to keep track of what cancellable objects you have and what timer is associated with it, present those objects to the user in some way, allowing them to pick one, and then implement a command that allows the user to actually cancel the object they've picked. Have you tried doing any of that? What _specifically_ do you need help with?

Comment: I have mentioned in the problem statement that I am using System.Threading.Timers and also if there can be alternate approach for this Can you explain a little bit? Thanks for helping!

Comment: Like I said, it doesn't matter which `Timer` implementation you're using (you're right, you did put that in your opening paragraph). They all have some equivalent mechanism. The real problem is with the rest of the question, which doesn't have a [mcve], doesn't explain what you've tried, doesn't provide a _specific_ issue that you need help with or are asking about. Please improve the question.

Comment: So think it like this that you have created two jobs in my application. Those two jobs are scheduled to repeat at some interval provided by user as per the scheduler code provided. Now they both use same method for scheduling timer but only difference being the task getting invoked. Now if user deletes Job1 how to handle timer 1 so that it doesn't affect timer 2 operation?

Comment: @DhimanshuJassal check my answer it's what you want.

Comment: You should use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` - then you can do this: `IDisposable scheduled = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromHours(1.0)).Subscribe(x => { /* Do action here */ });`. You can simply stop the scheduled action by calling `scheduled.Dispose();`. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution could be to create a custom class based on Timer. Just add whatever members you like and get your custom Timer object back from the "sender" argument of the "Elapsed" event handler:

And maybe you can add each timer in a `List` and on `Elapsed` event after performing your task (whatever) you go find that timer in that `List of Timers` on the bases of `Tag` and `Stop` or `Dispose` that specific timer

```
 class CustomTimer : System.Timers.Timer
    {
        public string Tag;
    }

    private void StartTimer()
    {
        var timer = new CustomTimer
        {
            Interval = 3000,
            Tag= "FirstTimer"
        };

        timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
        timer.Start();
    }

    void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        string tag = ((CustomTimer)sender).Tag;
        // perform whatever operation
        // here compare this timer in existing timers list 
        // and stop this timer
    }
```

Comment: Thank You very much for the help! Your approach got me thinking and I implemented a new AutoResetEvent.WaitOne() just before the dispose command and then implemented and signalled it such that if my Job definitions file exist in the directory in which i am storing job definitions for particular job , it signalled it and the particular thread got disposed off without even altering the second timer. I am signalling the Event from the action which will be executed every time once the timecallback method is called. Thank you everyone for their valuable inputs.

Comment: good to hear that :) maybe you will consider accepting it as answer or upvoting thanks